# Configuring and Building DCIe on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, image-processing, cmake, build

I am trying to install a package called DICe available here: https://github.com/dicengine/dice on my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS using source code. This package requires another package called Trilinos : https://trilinos.github.io/ . I have successfully build the Trilinos in the following path: `~/Documents/Trilinos/`. Now the problem is, when I try to build the DCIe in `~/Documents/DCIe/` it shows error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:22 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindTrilinos.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Trilinos",
  but CMake did not find one.
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Trilinos" with any
  of the following names:

    TrilinosConfig.cmake
    trilinos-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Trilinos" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Trilinos_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Trilinos" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
```

I have extracted DCIe source code in `~/Downloads/dice2.0`. Can someone guide me how I am supposed to configure the CmakeLists.txt? Here is my changed version:

````
MESSAGE("\nConfiguring DICe...\n")

# check if the pre-compiled set of libraries and header for windows is being used:
IF(DEFINED DICE_DEVPACK_DIR)
  MESSAGE(STATUS "***Using DevPack from: ${DICE_DEVPACK_DIR}")
  MESSAGE(STATUS "Note: if any of the following variables have been defined, they will be reset\n   DICE_TRILINOS_DIR\n   OpenCV_DIR\n   CLAPACK_DIR\n   NetCDF_DIR\n   HDF5_DIR")
  SET(DICE_TRILINOS_DIR "${DICE_DEVPACK_DIR}/trilinos")
  SET(OpenCV_DIR "${DICE_DEVPACK_DIR}/opencv")
  SET(NetCDF_DIR "${DICE_DEVPACK_DIR}/netcdf/lib")
  SET(HDF5_DIR "${DICE_DEVPACK_DIR}/netcdf/lib")
  SET(CLAPACK_DIR "${DICE_DEVPACK_DIR}/lapack")
  link_directories(${CLAPACK_DIR}/F2CLIBS)
ENDIF()

# Try to find Trilinos, if path was not given
IF (NOT DEFINED DICE_TRILINOS_DIR)
  # Losely based on:
  # https://github.com/trilinos/Trilinos_tutorial/wiki/CMakeFindPackageTrilinosExample
  # /usr/share/doc/opencv-doc/examples/face/CMakeLists.txt
  # * Find Trilinos
  find_package(Trilinos REQUIRED)

  IF(Trilinos_FOUND)
    MESSAGE("\nFound Trilinos")
    SET(DICE_TRILINOS_DIR ${Trilinos_DIR})
    MESSAGE("Trilinos_DIR = ${DICE_TRILINOS_DIR}")
  ELSE()
    MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find Trilinos")
  ENDIF()
ENDIF()

MESSAGE(STATUS "Using Trilinos installed in: ${DICE_TRILINOS_DIR}")

# If this is a windows build CLAPACK is required. Find package for
# clapack is automatically enabled by setting the CLAPACK_DIR variable
IF(WIN32 AND NOT DEFINED DICE_DEVPACK_DIR)
   # must defined clapack_dir
  IF (NOT DEFINED CLAPACK_DIR)
    MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "\nDICe Error: this is a windows build, so cmake must define CLAPACK_DIR:
    (-D CLAPACK_DIR:FILEPATH=<clapack_install_prefix>)!")
  ENDIF()
  FIND_PACKAGE(clapack PATHS ${CLAPACK_DIR})
  IF(clapack_FOUND)
    MESSAGE("\nFound CLAPACK in ${CLAPACK_DIR}")
    link_directories(${CLAPACK_DIR}/F2CLIBS/libf2c)
  ELSE()
    MESSAGE("\nERROR: could not find CLAPACK in the following directory: ${CLAPACK_DIR}")
  ENDIF()
ENDIF()
IF(WIN32)
  IF(NOT BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
    MESSAGE("\nWarning: This is a windows build, but BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is OFF. Setting BUILD_SHARED_LIBS on automatically.")
    SET(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ON)
  ENDIF(NOT BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
ENDIF(WIN32)

IF(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
  MESSAGE(STATUS "BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is set to ON")
ELSE(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)
  MESSAGE(STATUS "BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is set to OFF")
ENDIF(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS)

# Get Trilinos as one entity
# SET(Trilinos_DIR CACHE PATH "~/Documents/Trilinos")
SET(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${DICE_TRILINOS_DIR} ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})
FIND_PACKAGE(Trilinos PATHS ~/Documents/Trilinos)

IF(NOT Trilinos_FOUND)
  MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find Trilinos!")
ENDIF()

MESSAGE("\nFound Trilinos!  Here are the details: ")
MESSAGE("   Trilinos_DIR = ${Trilinos_DIR}")
MESSAGE("   Trilinos_VERSION = ${Trilinos_VERSION}")
MESSAGE("   Trilinos_PACKAGE_LIST = ${Trilinos_PACKAGE_LIST}")
MESSAGE("   Trilinos_LIBRARIES = ${Trilinos_LIBRARIES}")
MESSAGE("   Trilinos_INCLUDE_DIRS = ${Trilinos_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
MESSAGE("   Trilinos_LIBRARY_DIRS = ${Trilinos_LIBRARY_DIRS}")
MESSAGE("   Trilinos_TPL_LIST = ${Trilinos_TPL_LIST}")
MESSAGE("   Trilinos_TPL_INCLUDE_DIRS = ${Trilinos_TPL_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
MESSAGE("   Trilinos_TPL_LIBRARIES = ${Trilinos_TPL_LIBRARIES}")
MESSAGE("   Trilinos_TPL_LIBRARY_DIRS = ${Trilinos_TPL_LIBRARY_DIRS}")
MESSAGE("   Trilinos_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS = ${Trilinos_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS}")
MESSAGE("End of Trilinos details\n")

IF(NOT DEFINED DICE_DEVPACK_DIR)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${Trilinos_CXX_COMPILER} )
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${Trilinos_C_COMPILER} )
ENDIF()
SET(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE OFF)

IF(NOT DEFINED DICE_MPI_EXEC)
  SET(DICE_MPI_EXEC mpiexec)
ENDIF()
# End of setup and error checking
#  NOTE: PROJECT command checks for compilers, so this statement
#        is moved AFTER setting CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER opton

PROJECT(DICe)

MESSAGE(STATUS "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE: ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}")
SET(DICE_OUTPUT_PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
MESSAGE(STATUS "The output directory for DICe libraries will be: ${DICE_OUTPUT_PREFIX}/lib")
MESSAGE(STATUS "If 'make install' is exectued, the libraries will also be copied to: ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib")

# See if tracklib is available
IF(DEFINED TRACKLIB_DIR)
  MESSAGE(STATUS "TRACKLIB is ON")
  MESSAGE(STATUS "TRACKLIB_DIR is set to: ${TRACKLIB_DIR}")
  ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DDICE_ENABLE_TRACKLIB=1)
ELSE()
  MESSAGE(STATUS "TRACKLIB is OFF")
ENDIF()

# Try to find OpenCV, if path was not given
IF (NOT DEFINED OpenCV_DIR)
  # Losely based on:
  # https://github.com/trilinos/Trilinos_tutorial/wiki/CMakeFindPackageTrilinosExample
  # /usr/share/doc/opencv-doc/examples/face/CMakeLists.txt
  # * Find OpenCV
  message(STATUS "OpenCV_DIR not specified, looking in default paths")
  find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
ELSE()
  message(STATUS "Looking for OpenCV in dir: ${OpenCV_DIR}")
  find_package( OpenCV NO_DEFAULT_PATH PATHS ${OpenCV_DIR} )
ENDIF()
IF(OpenCV_FOUND)
  set(DICE_ENABLE_OPENCV ON)
  IF(WIN32)
    FILE(GLOB OPENCV_DLLS ${OpenCV_DIR}/x64/vc12/bin/*.dll)
    FILE(COPY ${OPENCV_DLLS} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
    FILE(GLOB OPENCV_DLLS ${OpenCV_DIR}/x64/vc15/bin/*.dll)
    FILE(COPY ${OPENCV_DLLS} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
  ENDIF()
ELSE()
  message(FATAL_ERROR "OpenCV not found. OpenCV is now a required package in DICe")
ENDIF()

# FIND NETCDF
set(DICE_ENABLE_NETCDF OFF)
if(DEFINED NetCDF_DIR)
  set(DICE_ENABLE_NETCDF ON)
  MESSAGE(STATUS "Looking for NetCDF in: ${NetCDF_DIR}")
  find_library(NetCDF_lib NAMES libnetcdf.a netcdf PATHS ${NetCDF_DIR})
  MESSAGE(STATUS "Looking for HDF5 in: ${HDF5_DIR}")
  find_library(HDF5_lib NAMES libhdf5.a hdf5 PATHS ${HDF5_DIR} NO_DEFAULT_PATH)  
  find_library(HDF5_lib NAMES libhdf5.a hdf5 PATHS ${HDF5_DIR})  
  find_library(HDF5_hl_lib NAMES libhdf5_hl.a hdf5_hl PATHS ${HDF5_DIR} NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
  find_library(HDF5_hl_lib NAMES libhdf5_hl.a hdf5_hl PATHS ${HDF5_DIR})
  MESSAGE(STATUS "Using NetCDF lib: ${NetCDF_lib}")
  MESSAGE(STATUS "Using HDF5 libs: ${HDF5_lib} ${HDF5_hl_lib}")
  IF(NOT NetCDF_lib_NOTFOUND)
      SET(DICE_LIBRARIES ${DICE_LIBRARIES} ${NetCDF_lib})
      SET(DICE_LIBRARIES ${DICE_LIBRARIES} ${HDF5_lib})
      SET(DICE_LIBRARIES ${DICE_LIBRARIES} ${HDF5_hl_lib})
      ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DDICE_ENABLE_NETCDF=1)
      include_directories(${NetCDF_DIR}/../include)
      link_directories(${NetCDF_DIR}/../lib)
      IF(WIN32)
        FILE(GLOB NetCDF_DLLS ${NetCDF_DIR}/../bin/*.dll)
        FILE(COPY ${NetCDF_DLLS} DESTINATION ${DICE_OUTPUT_PREFIX}/bin)
      ENDIF()
  ELSE()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Error, NetCDF enabled but not found")
  ENDIF()
else()
  MESSAGE(STATUS "NetCDF will NOT be enabled")
endif()

#
# Hypercine library for reading cine files
#
include(ExternalProject)
MESSAGE(STATUS "Configuring hypercine")
SET(HYPERCINE_CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX} -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} -DHYPERCINE_DEBUG_MSG:BOOL=${DICE_DEBUG_MSG} -DOpenCV_DIR:PATH=${OpenCV_DIR})
# base data type:
if(DICE_USE_INT_STORAGE)
  SET(HYPERCINE_CMAKE_ARGS ${HYPERCINE_CMAKE_ARGS} -DHYPERCINE_USE_INT_STORAGE:BOOL=ON)
  ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DUSE_INT_STORAGE=1)
elseif(DICE_USE_DOUBLE)
  SET(HYPERCINE_CMAKE_ARGS ${HYPERCINE_CMAKE_ARGS} -DHYPERCINE_USE_DOUBLE_STORAGE:BOOL=ON)
  ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DUSE_DOUBLE_STORAGE=1)
else()
  SET(HYPERCINE_CMAKE_ARGS ${HYPERCINE_CMAKE_ARGS} -DHYPERCINE_USE_FLOAT_STORAGE:BOOL=ON)
  ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DUSE_FLOAT_STORAGE=1)
endif()
ExternalProject_Add(hypercine
  GIT_REPOSITORY git://github.com/dicengine/hypercine.git
  PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/hypercine
  CMAKE_ARGS ${HYPERCINE_CMAKE_ARGS}
)

# base data type:
if(DICE_USE_DOUBLE)
  ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DDICE_USE_DOUBLE=1)
  MESSAGE(STATUS "Scalar type will be: DOUBLE")
else()
  MESSAGE(STATUS "Scalar type will be: FLOAT (default)")
endif()
if(DICE_USE_INT_STORAGE)
  ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DDICE_USE_INT_STORAGE=1)
  MESSAGE(STATUS "Image intensity storage type will be: INT")
else()
  IF(DICE_USE_DOUBLE)
    MESSAGE(STATUS "Image intensity storage type will be: DOUBLE")
  ELSE()
    MESSAGE(STATUS "Image intensity storage type will be: FLOAT (default)")
  ENDIF()
endif()

# MPI check -- defaults to TRUE
LIST(FIND Trilinos_TPL_LIST MPI MPI_List_ID)
IF (MPI_List_ID GREATER -1)
  MESSAGE(STATUS "Checking if MPI is enabled in Trilinos: MPI ENABLED")
  SET(DICE_MPI TRUE)
  ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DDICE_MPI=1)
  MESSAGE(STATUS "Using DICE_MPI_EXEC: ${DICE_MPI_EXEC}")
ELSE()
  MESSAGE(STATUS "Checking if MPI is enabled in Trilinos: MPI NOT ENABLED")
  SET(DICE_MPI FALSE)
ENDIF()

SET(DICE_TRILINOS_HEADERS
    ${Trilinos_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${Trilinos_TPL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  )

SET(DICE_TRILINOS_LIB_DIRS
    ${Trilinos_LIBRARY_DIRS}
    ${Trilinos_TPL_LIBRARY_DIRS}
  )

link_directories(${DICE_TRILINOS_LIB_DIRS})

ExternalProject_Get_Property(hypercine source_dir)
include_directories(${source_dir}/src)
set(libprefix "lib")
set(libsuffix ".a")
if(WIN32)
  set(libprefix "")
  set(libsuffix ".lib")
endif()
set(DICE_LIBRARIES ${DICE_LIBRARIES} "${libprefix}hypercine${libsuffix}")
set(DICE_UTILS_LIBRARIES ${DICE_UTILS_LIBRARIES} "${libprefix}hypercine${libsuffix}")
link_directories(${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib)
if(WIN32)
link_directories(${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin)
endif()

SET(DICE_HEADER_DIRS
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/api
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/base
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/core
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/netcdf
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/fft
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/ioutils
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/rawi
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/kdtree
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/mesh
  )
IF(DEFINED TRACKLIB_DIR)
  SET(DICE_HEADER_DIRS
    ${DICE_HEADER_DIRS}
    ${TRACKLIB_DIR}/src/
  )
ENDIF()

MESSAGE(STATUS "DICE_ENABLE_GLOBAL: ${DICE_ENABLE_GLOBAL}")
IF(DICE_ENABLE_GLOBAL)
  IF(NOT DICE_USE_DOUBLE)
      MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "DICE_ENABLE_GLOBAL can only be used with DICE_USE_DOUBLE=ON")
  ENDIF(NOT DICE_USE_DOUBLE)

  SET(DICE_HEADER_DIRS
      ${DICE_HEADER_DIRS}
      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/global
      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/mesh/io
      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/global/triangle)
      add_definitions(-DTRILIBRARY -DANSI_DECLARATORS -DDICE_ENABLE_GLOBAL=1)
ENDIF()

IF(DICE_ENABLE_OPENCV)
  SET(DICE_HEADER_DIRS
      ${DICE_HEADER_DIRS}      
      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/opencv
  )
  add_definitions(-DDICE_ENABLE_OPENCV=1)
ENDIF()

SET(DICE_LIBRARIES
    ${DICE_LIBRARIES}
    teuchoscore
    teuchosnumerics
    teuchoscomm
    teuchosparameterlist
 )

IF(DICE_ENABLE_GLOBAL)
  MESSAGE(STATUS "*** Enabling Global DIC (requires the Tpetra (or Epetra), Seacas libraries, and Belos in Trilinos) ***")
  IF(DICE_USE_TPETRA)
    SET(DICE_LIBRARIES
      ${DICE_LIBRARIES}
      tpetra
      exodus
      belos
      belostpetra
    )
    ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DDICE_TPETRA=1)
  ELSE()
    SET(DICE_LIBRARIES
      ${DICE_LIBRARIES}
      epetra
      exodus
      belos
      ifpack
      belosepetra
    )
  ENDIF()
ELSE()
  MESSAGE(STATUS "Global DIC will not be enabled (to enable, set -D DICE_ENABLE_GLOBAL:BOOL=ON in the CMake script)")
  SET(DICE_LIBRARIES
    ${DICE_LIBRARIES}
    epetra
  )
ENDIF()

# WINDOWS CMake has a bug for find_package() for clapack
# f2clibs have to be added manually here
IF(WIN32)
  SET(DICE_LIBRARIES ${DICE_LIBRARIES} libf2c)
ENDIF()

# if debug messages are turned on:
IF(DICE_DEBUG_MSG)
  MESSAGE(STATUS "Debugging messages are ON")
  ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DDICE_DEBUG_MSG=1)
ELSE(DICE_DEBUG_MSG)
  MESSAGE(STATUS "Debugging messages are OFF")
ENDIF(DICE_DEBUG_MSG)

# Windows: use Trilinos compiler flags
# Linux: don't use compiler flags from Trilinos, instead set them manually
# but pick up openmp if Trilinos was compiled with it:
if(WIN32)
  SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${Trilinos_CXX_COMPILER_FLAGS})
  SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS ${Trilinos_C_COMPILER_FLAGS}) 
Else()
  SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}  -O3")
  STRING(FIND ${Trilinos_CXX_COMPILER_FLAGS} "openmp" OpenMPFound)
  IF( ${OpenMPFound} GREATER -1 )
    MESSAGE(STATUS "OpenMP was enabled in Trilinos so enabling it here. (Found flag at position ${OpenMPFound})")
    SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}  -fopenmp")
    SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}  -fopenmp")
  ENDIF()
  STRING(FIND ${Trilinos_CXX_COMPILER_FLAGS} "c++11" CXX11Found)
  IF( ${CXX11Found} GREATER -1 )
    MESSAGE(STATUS "c++11 was enabled in Trilinos so enabling it here. (Found flag at position ${CXX11Found})")
  ELSE()
    MESSAGE(WARNING "could not find c++11 flag for Trilinos (c++11 is required)")
  ENDIF()
    SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}  -std=c++11")
endif()
MESSAGE(STATUS "Trilinos CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS: ${Trilinos_CXX_COMPILER_FLAGS}")
MESSAGE(STATUS "Trilinos CMAKE_C_FLAGS: ${Trilinos_C_COMPILER_FLAGS}")
MESSAGE(STATUS "DICe CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS: ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
MESSAGE(STATUS "DICe CMAKE_C_FLAGS: ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}")

# Get the git information to put in the header message (to identify the commit corresponding
# to the executable that was run
execute_process(
  COMMAND git describe --abbrev=6 --dirty --always --tags
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE GIT_SHA1
    OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE)
MESSAGE(STATUS "Git sha1: ${GIT_SHA1}")
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DGITSHA1=\"${GIT_SHA1}\")

add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(tools)
add_subdirectory(tests) ```

Thank you in advance.
Edit: I am using Ububtu in VirtualBox.
````

Comment: "I have successfully build the Trilinos..." - You need to **install** Trilinos, and assign its **installation prefix** to variable `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`, exactly as the error message tells you.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks a lot! I just went through the Cmake documentation and found out the way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

As @Tsyvarev rightly pointed out, I just added following lines to the CmakeLists.txt of DICe :

`LIST(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "PATH TO TRILINOS INSTALLATION")`

Hope it helps others like me. Peace.